# Pandas reshape DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

> I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {"start_date" : ["2018-04-30", "2018-05-01"]
       ,"end_date"   : ["2018-05-01", "2018-05-02"]
       ,"budget"      : [10, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"])
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"])

df

        budget  end_date    start_date 
  0       10    2018-05-01  2018-04-30
  1       12    2018-05-02  2018-05-01
```

> I would like to reshape my dataframe (split rows) to look like this:

```
      daily_average     days    end_date    start_date
    0      5         2018-04-30 2018-05-01  2018-04-30
    1      5         2018-05-01 2018-05-01  2018-04-30
    2      6         2018-05-01 2018-05-02  2018-05-01
    3      6         2018-05-02 2018-05-02  2018-05-01
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [python - Duplicate rows x number of times based on a value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659378/python-duplicate-rows-x-number-of-times-based-on-a-value-in-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on this thread:

[python - Duplicate rows x number of times based on a value in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659378/python-duplicate-rows-x-number-of-times-based-on-a-value-in-a-column)

```
df['Number of days'] = (df['end_date']-df['start_date']).map(lambda x: x.days)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Number of days']+1)]
df['days'] =(df.groupby(level=0)['start_date']
                     .transform(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x.iat[0], periods=len(x))))
df['daily_average'] = df['budget']/(df['Number of days']+1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[['daily_average', 'days', 'end_date', 'start_date']]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer!
This solution works correctly for the dataframe from my example.
But in fact I'm searching a solution which could work also for dataframes with more then one day between "start_date" and "end_date".
Do you have any idea how I could proceed in this case?

Comment: I think this is a better solution, and it cover yours problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659378/python-duplicate-rows-x-number-of-times-based-on-a-value-in-a-column